# Custom syntax highlighting for content of <script> elements depending on type attribute in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In IDEA, when editing a HTML file, the text content of `<script>` elements will be treated differently by the IDE according to the `type` attribute. For example, the text content of a `<script type="text/javascript">` element is treated as Javascript and highlighted as such; similar for `<script type="text/css">` and CSS, `<script type="application/json">` and JSON, and others.

How can I configure a custom `<script type="...">` language association?

Specifically, I want IDEA to treat the text content of script elements of type `"x-shader/x-fragment"` as GLSL. I have a GLSL language plugin installed, but it only highlights `.glsl` files. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3.

NB: There is no *Inject Language/Reference* option for the content of `<script>` elements, unlike other HTML elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure this, but this is trivial to fix in the GLSL plugin. In the Language class for GLSL ([here](https://code.google.com/p/glsl4idea/source/browse/src/glslplugin/lang/GLSLLanguage.java)), the "x-shader/x-fragment" MIME type needs to be passed as the second parameter to the base class constructor.

Comment: Couldn't get the code from the linked repository to compile, but made the relevant change in a local clone of https://github.com/Darkyenus/glsl4idea and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yole's answer is probably the best for your use case, but I actually ran into a similar issue where Intellij wasn't treating "text/babel" as "text/jsx" like I wanted.

If you don't mind moving the content of your script to another file, you could do something like this:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" src="your_script.glsl"></script>
```

Then of course you'd get the proper syntax highlighting when you edit the file.